# Override default jkube deployment name

Tags: maven, fabric8-maven-plugin, jkube

Is it possible to override the default deployment naming in jkube? I want to do something similar to the docker image naming where I can provide a pattern.

The deployment section in the [resources documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/docs/kubernetes-maven-plugin#k8s:resource) looked promising but those options are not present in the plugin.

The default naming appears to be the maven ${project.artifactId} but I have not found that documented anywhere. Digging through the code I can see the ResourceConfig is out of sync with the documentation and the examples.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply. Could you please check with enricher configuration? Try running `k8s:resource` with `-Djkube.enricher.jkube-controller.name=your-desired-name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from Eclipse JKube/FMP's development team. I think you should be able to override default controller name by either using `jkube.enricher.jkube-controller.name` property or by providing XML configuration for `jkube-controller` (Enricher which is responsible for default `Deployment` by plugin) like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jkube</groupId>
        <artifactId>kubernetes-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-alpha-1</version>
        <configuration>
            <enricher>
                <config>
                    <jkube-controller>
                        <name>some-deployment</name>
                    </jkube-controller>
                </config>
            </enricher>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

When I tried this, I was able to see `Deployment`'s name being changed as per our configuration:

```
~/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project : $ mvn k8s:resource k8s:apply
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< meetup:random-generator >-----------------------
[INFO] Building random-generator 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.0.0-alpha-1:resource (default-cli) @ random-generator ---
[INFO] k8s: Running generator spring-boot
[INFO] k8s: spring-boot: Using Docker image fabric8/java-centos-openjdk8-jdk:1.5 as base / builder
[INFO] k8s: jkube-controller: Adding a default Deployment
[INFO] k8s: jkube-service: Adding a default service 'random-generator' with ports [8080]
[INFO] k8s: jkube-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding readiness probe on port 8080, path='/actuator/health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 10 seconds
[INFO] k8s: jkube-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding liveness probe on port 8080, path='/actuator/health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 180 seconds
[INFO] k8s: jkube-revision-history: Adding revision history limit to 2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.0.0-alpha-1:apply (default-cli) @ random-generator ---
[INFO] k8s: Using Kubernetes at https://192.168.39.93:8443/ in namespace default with manifest /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/kubernetes.yml 
[INFO] k8s: Using namespace: default
[INFO] k8s: Creating a Service from kubernetes.yml namespace default name random-generator
[INFO] k8s: Created Service: target/jkube/applyJson/default/service-random-generator.json
[INFO] k8s: Creating a Deployment from kubernetes.yml namespace default name some-deployment
[INFO] k8s: Created Deployment: target/jkube/applyJson/default/deployment-some-deployment.json
[INFO] k8s: HINT: Use the command `kubectl get pods -w` to watch your pods start up
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.076 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-03T16:57:04+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project : $ kubectl get deploy
NAME              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
some-deployment   0/1     1            0           8s
~/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-demo-project : $ kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
some-deployment-97495447b-z9p48   0/1     Running   0          15s
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue. I had switched back to the fabric8 version for some other issues. I'll try going back to jkube now and to submit a pull request for controller docs. I still think the overlap between the enrichers and the resources is confusing.

Comment: @Bill: Much appreciated, Thanks a lot for trying out Eclipse JKube.